# If $x_{1} = \frac{1}{2}$ and $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{1-x_{n}}\;\;\forall\; n\; \geq 1\;,$ Then $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x_{n}=$

Tags: limits

> If $\displaystyle x_{1} = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\displaystyle x_{n+1} = \sqrt{1-x_{n}}\;\;\forall\;  n\; \geq 1\;,$ Then $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x_{n}=$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Although we know that when $x\rightarrow \infty\;,$ Then $x_{n+1}= x_{n} = l>0(\bf{say})$

Then we get $$l=\sqrt{1-l}\Rightarrow l^2=1-l\Rightarrow l^2+l-1=0$$

So we get $$l=\frac{-1+ \sqrt{5}}{2}\;,$$ bcz $l>0$

My question is how can we prove that the folowing sequence is Monotonic(either strictly increasing and decreasing function.)

and the sequence is bounded, Help required, Thanks

Comment: I think you means $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$. And the sequence is not monotonic.

Answer (score 3):

This sequence is in fact not monotonic. You can see this by computing the first few terms:
\begin{align*}
a_1 &= 0.5\\
a_2 &= 0.7071\\
a_3 &= 0.5411\\
a_4 &= 0.6773
\end{align*}

So you cannot claim that the sequence is bounded and monotonic to ensure the existence of a limit. However, you can use the [Banach Fixed Point Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem#Statement).

First, you can show that $\frac12\leq x_n\leq\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$ for all $n\geq1$ using induction. The base case is given since $x_1=\frac12$. Now assume that $\frac12\leq x_n\leq\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$ for some $n\geq1$. Then $\frac{1-\sqrt2}{2}\leq 1-x_n\leq \frac12$, and taking the square root gives
$$\frac12<\frac{\sqrt{1-\sqrt2}}{\sqrt2}\leq x_{n+1}\leq\frac{\sqrt2}{2}.$$

Use $X=\big[\frac12,\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\big]$ as your metric space with the usual Euclidean metric and $T:X\to X$, $T(x)=\sqrt{1-x}$ as your contraction mapping. I'll leave it to you to check the conditions of the Banach Fixed Point Theorem. The key point is to find some $q\in[0,1)$ such that
$$\left|\sqrt{1-x}-\sqrt{1-y}\right|\leq q\left|x-y\right|$$
for all $x,y\in X$.

So the function $T$ has a fixed point (which is the $l$ that you have already found) and this fixed point is the limit of your sequence.

Comment: Why does the existence of a fixed point show that the sequence converges?

Comment: It's in the statement of the Banach Fixed Point Theorem. A sequence starting at any point in $X$ defined recursively through $T$ converges to the (unique) fixed point of $T$.

Comment: It is not particularly easy to find $q$. For example $\sqrt{1-0.7024}-\sqrt{1-0.707}>0.92(0.707-0.7024)$.

Comment: For $x,y\in [1/2,\sqrt 2 /2]$ we have  $f(x),f(y)\in [1/2,\sqrt 2 /2]$ and $|f(x)-f(y)|=$ $|x-y|(f(x)+f(y))^{-1}$ $\leq |x-y|/2 f(\sqrt 2 /2)\leq |x-y|/1.08$.

Comment: In my comment above, the function $f(x)=\sqrt {1-x}.$  I ran out of editing time.

Answer (score 2):

We have $0<x_n<1$ for all $n$ by induction.(That is, the positive number $x_n$ exists for all $n.)$

With $l=(-1+\sqrt 5)2$ we have $l^2=1-l.$ Using this, show that $$x_n<l\implies x_n<x_{n+2}<l$$ $$\text {and } \quad  x_n>l\implies x_n>x_{n+2}>l.$$  $$ \text {So } \quad x_1<x_3<x_5<...<l<...<x_6<x_4<x_2.$$ Now let $A=\lim_{n\to \infty}x_{2 n-1}$ and $B=\lim_{n\to \infty}x_{2 n}.$

To show $A=B,$ note that $$A=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt {1-x_{2 n}}=\sqrt {1-B}$$ $$\text {and that }\quad  B=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt {1-x_{2 n-1}}=\sqrt {1-A}.$$

So $A^2=1-B, $ and $ B^2=1-A,$ implying $A^2-B^2=A-B.$ Hence  $A\ne B \implies  A+B=1. $

But $A>x_1=1/2$ and $B\geq l.$ So $A+B>1/2+l>1.$ Therefore $A=B.$

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x) = \sqrt{1 -x}$. Then $f$ is strictly decreasing, which shows that $x_0 < x_1$, $x_1 > x_2$, $x_2 < x_3$, etc. The sequence is neither increasing nor decreasing.

Though, the subsequences of odd and even indices are both monotonic.

Hint: Consider

$$f(x) = \sqrt{ 1 - \sqrt{ 1 -x}}$$

Prove that it is increasing and note that for all $n \ge 1$: $$\begin{cases} x_{2n + 2} = f(x_{2n}) \\ x_{2n + 1} = f(x_{2n - 1})\end{cases}$$

Comment: Yes, that is all the OP asked for, but it does not show that the sequence converges. So far, it is still possible that the odd and even terms tend to different limits.

Comment: @almagest yes, but the point is that we know that they converge. I did not say that the sequence converges